# Python 2.7 - If statement evaluates incorrectly when using .lower string modifier

Tags: python-2.7

New to Python and coding in general. I've tried to implement a simple code that will evaluate user input as either Y or N. If the answer is N, then the script should stop running. Otherwise, it should continue (in this case, printing a statement). Seems to work fine when I enter the exact string that is called for in the if statement. However, if I try to evaluate the answer using the .lower modifier, it just seems to ignore the input and proceed no matter what. Any assistance would be welcome. See code below. Thank you!

```
answer = str(raw_input("Enter Y or N: "))
if answer.lower == 'n':
    quit()
else:
    print "Cool! Next question."
```

Answer (score 6):

You're not calling `.lower`, you're comparing the *function* `.lower` to the string 'n'.  That will never be true.

Try this code snippet instead:

```
if answer.lower() == 'n':
```